# Java EE application fails to compile due to package that do not exist when using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish-4.1

I am beginner in Java and I have a problem when using:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

Compiler writes this error:

```
Error:(3, 32) java: package javax.enterprise.context does not exist
Error:(4, 20) java: package javax.inject does not exist
Error:(6, 2) java: cannot find symbol symbol: class Named
Error:(7, 2) java: cannot find symbol symbol: class RequestScoped
```

I think it will be problem with path to the packages or something like it. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14, GlassFish 4.1.1. On NetBeans it works fine but I want to try IntelliJ IDEA.

My code:

```
package beans;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RandNumberBean {

    private Random randGenerator;

    public RandNumberBean() {
        randGenerator = new Random();
    }

    public int getRandNumber() {
        return randGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are a beginner, you should start at the beginning. It would seem like the library you need is in the path of netbeans, but not on the path of your intelliJ installation

Comment: If you're using the Community Edition of IntelliJ IDEA, you won't have access to JavaEE functionalities of the IDE as Jetbrains lock them out for the Community Edition. You'll need to purchase a license for IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to access JavaEE related IDE functionality.

Answer (score 4):

### Adding the Java EE 7 API dependency

Once it's a Java EE application, consider adding the [Java EE 7 API](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api/7.0) dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It includes packages such as `javax.enterprise.context` and `javax.inject`.

This dependency only includes the [Java EE 7 specifications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javaee/tech/index.html). The implementations for such specifications are provided by application servers such as [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/) and [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/).

### Defining an application server in IntelliJ IDEA

To run and debug your application, you need to define an application server (e.g. GlassFish) in your IDE. Here are the steps, according to the IntelliJ IDEA [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/defining-application-servers-in-intellij-idea.html):

1. Open the [Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/accessing-settings.html) dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).
2. In the left-hand pane, in the *Build, Execution, Deployment* category, select *Application Servers*.
3. On the *Application Servers* page that opens in the right-hand part of the dialog, click [image: add] (Alternatively, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>).
4. Select the server that you are going to use.
5. In the dialog that opens, specify the server settings and click *OK*. For most of the servers, you have to specify just the server home, i.e. the server installation directory. For more information, see [Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/application-servers-2.html).
6. Click *OK* in the *Settings dialog*.

---

But be aware IntelliJ IDEA Community [does not support Java EE development](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/#chooseYourEdition). If you need to develop Java EE applications and you are using the Community version, consider purchasing a IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate license.

Answer (score 3):

The library you want to use isn't included in `Java SE`, you need to use `Java EE` and by default `Intellij IDEA` community edition doesn't include the `Java EE` features and for that  you need to specify an application server in `Settings | Application Servers`.

Configure a global library for your application server jars and add it to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html?origin=old_help)

If you're a beginner, you should lookup some [tutorials](https://dzone.com/articles/headless-setup-java-project) about Tomcat and how to use it with Intellij first.

Comment: @lukas-navratil, you should accept the answer if you consider it is useful